# How to implement auto-incrementing version number column?

Tags: sql-server

What is a good way to implement a field in SQL Server that is auto-incrementing based on another field in the same table? Imagine a `VersionNumber` field that is auto-incrementing `1` to `n`, *for each value* of column `DocumentID`.

Requirements:

- VersionNumber must start at 1, and not skip any numbers
- The VersionNumber column must be persisted. It cannot be dynamically created in a view, such as via `ROW_NUMBER`. The point of this is creating an audit trail.
- Ideally, direct inserts and updates of VersionNumber would be prevented

**In Detail**

I'm designing a database that requires versioned data. The basic structure for this sort of thing is to have a header table with invariant fields and a version detail table with:

- A foreign key to the header table
- A version number
- Fields than can change from version to version

Articles such as [SQL Strategies for 'Versioned' Data](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-strategies-for-versioned-data/) and [Yet Another SQL Strategy for Versioned Data](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/yet-another-sql-strategy-for-versioned-data/) discuss strategies for efficiently querying this type of structure, but not the actual implementation of the `VersionNumber` field (the second article provides a partial example, but leaves a fuller implementation for 'an advanced exercise').

Example DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE Invoice (
    InvoiceID   bigint identity(1,1) not null primary key,
    CreateDate  date not null
);

CREATE TABLE InvoiceVersion ( 
    InvoiceVersionID  bigint identity(1,1) not null primary key,
    InvoiceID         bigint not null,
    VersionNumber     int not null
    Other Fields...

    CONSTRAINT FK_InvoiceVersion_Invoice
    FOREIGN KEY ( InvoiceID ) 
    REFERENCES Invoice ( InvoiceID )
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_InvoiceVersion
    ON InvoiceVersion ( InvoiceID, VersionNumber )
;
```

My partial solution addresses incrementing the version number on insert, but does not prevent selective deletes of specific versions, or prevent direct updates of `VersionNumber`. I'd love it, though, if all this didn't require three 50-line triggers.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_InvoiceVersion_Insert
    ON InvoiceVersion
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    -- Prevent explicit VersionNumber insert
    DECLARE @ExplicitVersionCount int;

    SELECT @ExplicitVersionCount = COUNT(*)
    FROM inserted
    WHERE VersionNumber IS NOT NULL;

    IF (@ExplicitVersionCount > 0) BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Explicit version number insert not allowed', 15, 1);
    END

    -- Get the current version number (implicit in row count)
    DECLARE @InsertingInvoiceID TABLE (
        InvoiceID bigint not null primary key 
    );

    DECLARE @CurrentVersions TABLE (
        InvoiceID bigint not null primary key,
        VersionCount int
    );

    INSERT INTO @InsertingInvoiceID ( InvoiceID )
    SELECT DISTINCT i.InvoiceID 
    FROM inserted i;

    INSERT INTO @CurrentVersions ( InvoiceID, VersionCount )
    SELECT I.InvoiceID, COUNT(V.InvoiceID)
    FROM @InsertingInvoiceID I
        LEFT JOIN migrate.InvoiceVersion V 
            ON V.InvoiceID = I.InvoiceID
    GROUP BY I.InvoiceID
    ;

    INSERT INTO InvoiceVersion (
        InvoiceID
      , VersionNumber
      , [Other fields...]
    )
    SELECT
        i.InvoiceID
      , v.VersionCount + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.InvoiceID ORDER BY i.InvoiceID)
      , [Other fields...]
    FROM inserted i
        INNER JOIN @CurrentVersions v
            ON i.InvoiceID = v.InvoiceID
    ;
END;
```

Comment: Say you have one `InvoiceID` with three versions.  Must the `VersionNumber`s be 1,2,3?  Or would something like 12,94,434 be acceptable? (12 being the first version, 94 the second, and 434 the third.)

Comment: @DMason It must be 1,2,3. You can delete all versions at once, but you cannot delete one version at a time. The *complete* history is important.

Comment: So the question is how to increment the version number when inserting in the InvoiceVersion table for an Invoice that already exists?

Comment: What about calculating ver # on the fly in your queries using `ROW_NUMBER() (OVER ORDER BY InvoiceID, InvoiceVersionID) AS VersionNumber`?  Is it a requirement to have the ver # data persisted? (I'm assuming table `InvoiceNumber` will have inserts only--no deletes.)

Comment: @DMason The version number should be persisted. I'm using `ROW_NUMBER()` to calculate these within an insert trigger; I'll post what I have so far

Comment: I wish I had more to add to this.  Great question, though.  I'm curious to see what solutions anyone can offer.

Comment: Instead of a trigger you might find that a computed column will be easier to maintain and less prone to logical errors.

Comment: When you delete  versions and start inserting new ones, do they have to restart at 1, or will they continue from where you stopped  ?

Comment: @RomanMik You should not be allowed to delete any versions--unless you delete ALL versions.

Comment: Is a new version created each time you insert or update an Invoice?

Answer (score 1):

I would be tempted to calculate it on the fly in a view.  Use the dates/id's at your disposal to identify version info automatically.

Omit the `VersionNumber` column from `InvoiceVersion`, and toss in a datetime w/a default value, and use a windowing function to calculate the version for you (once comfortable, make it a view).

Parition by the `InvoiceID`, and order by the `DateAdded` to the `InvoiceVersion` table, and the `InvoiceVersionID` in case two are added simultaneously.

Control over what is deleted should really be enforced on the front end, but could be done via a trigger that fires after delete, and restores the data if not all are deleted.  You could just grab the `InvoiceID`(s) from the deleted table in the trigger, and if the `InvoiceID`(s) still exists in the `InvoiceVersion` table, rollback and raise error.

Another option instead of actually deleting, is just adding a "deleted" bit column to the `Invoice` table.  Mark an invoice as "deleted", but never delete it from the table.  Then in your view, join the `Invoice` table, and add `where deleted=0`.

Hope this helps.

View Example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#Invoice') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Invoice
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#InvoiceVersion') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #InvoiceVersion

CREATE TABLE #Invoice (
    InvoiceID   bigint identity(1,1) not null primary key,
    CreateDate  datetime not null
);

CREATE TABLE #InvoiceVersion ( 
    InvoiceVersionID  bigint identity(1,1) not null primary key,
    InvoiceID         bigint not null,
    Col1              varchar(100),
    Col2              int,
    DateAdded         datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

-- CREATE Invoice#1 & Invoice#2
INSERT INTO #Invoice (CreateDate) SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
INSERT INTO #Invoice (CreateDate) SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

-- CREATE 1 "version" for Invoice#1 & 4 for Invoice#2 & then 1 more for Invoice#1
INSERT INTO #InvoiceVersion (InvoiceID, Col1, Col2) SELECT 1, 'TEST 1', 543
INSERT INTO #InvoiceVersion (InvoiceID, Col1, Col2) SELECT 2, 'TEST 2', 34
INSERT INTO #InvoiceVersion (InvoiceID, Col1, Col2) SELECT 2, 'TEST 2', 242
INSERT INTO #InvoiceVersion (InvoiceID, Col1, Col2) SELECT 2, 'TEST 2', 965
INSERT INTO #InvoiceVersion (InvoiceID, Col1, Col2) SELECT 2, 'TEST 2', 184
INSERT INTO #InvoiceVersion (InvoiceID, Col1, Col2) SELECT 1, 'TEST 1', 684

--SELECT * FROM #Invoice
--SELECT * FROM #InvoiceVersion

--CREATE VIEW VersionedInvoice
--AS
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY InvoiceID ORDER BY InvoiceID, DateAdded, InvoiceVersionID) as VersionNumber
FROM #InvoiceVersion
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't good enough. The whole point of keeping all the versions is for auditing. Thus we need to know that all the versions are present--or if a version was delete that needs to be known, too.

Comment: Now I'm confused, you said above you can delete ALL versions... you could easily put the delete bit in the InvoiceVersion table too, no?

Comment: Bob creates an invoice. (Version 1). Bob updates the invoice (Version 2). Sue updates the invoice (Version 3). We can delete all versions of the invoice (such as for old invoices rolling out of the document retention window), but we cannot just delete version 2. That destroys the audit trail.

Comment: That's fine, don't let them delete from `dbo.InvoiceVersion`... force them to change the delete flag in `dbo.Invoice`, or cascade/rollback the delete via trigger to delete all versions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option I would try.  Create INSTEAD OF triggers to prevent direct inserts, updates, or deletes on table InvoiceVersion.
Then create an "insert" stored proc that adds new versions to the InvoiceVersion table.
Create a "delete" stored proc that deletes all versions of an invoice by the version id.
Each proc will disable the related trigger, perform the required DML, then enable the trigger (all within a single transaction).

Could this work for you?

```
--Don't allow inserts to InvoiceVersion.
CREATE TRIGGER insInvoiceVersion 
ON InvoiceVersion
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('Direct inserts to table InvoiceVersion are not permitted.  Use stored proc InsertInvoiceVersion instead.', 16, 1);
END
GO

--Don't allow updates to InsertInvoiceVersion.
CREATE TRIGGER updInvoiceVersion 
ON InvoiceVersion
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('Direct updates of table InvoiceVersion are not permitted.', 16, 1);
END
GO

--Don't allow deletes from InsertInvoiceVersion.
CREATE TRIGGER delInvoiceVersion 
ON InvoiceVersion
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('Direct deletes from table InvoiceVersion are not permitted.  Use stored proc DeleteInvoiceVersions instead.', 16, 1);
END
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE InsertInvoiceVersion
    @InvoiceID BIGINT
    --Other fields
AS
BEGIN
    --Get the next version number. (This could be replaced with a UDF for convenience, if desired.)
    DECLARE @VersionNumber INT

    SELECT @VersionNumber = MAX(VersionNumber) +1
    FROM InvoiceVersion
    WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID

    --In case there are no existing versions of the invoice yet...
    SELECT @VersionNumber = COALESCE(@VersionNumber, 1)

    --Disable the insert trigger, insert, enable the insert trigger.
    ALTER TABLE InvoiceVersion DISABLE TRIGGER insInvoiceVersion

    INSERT INTO InvoiceVersion (InvoiceID, VersionNumber /*, other fields*/)
    VALUES (@InvoiceID, @VersionNumber /*, other fields*/)

    ALTER TABLE InvoiceVersion ENABLE TRIGGER insInvoiceVersion
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteInvoiceVersions
    @InvoiceID BIGINT
AS
    --Disable the delete trigger, delete, enable the delete trigger.
    ALTER TABLE InvoiceVersion DISABLE TRIGGER delInvoiceVersion

    DELETE FROM InvoiceVersion
    WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID

    ALTER TABLE InvoiceVersion ENABLE TRIGGER delInvoiceVersion
GO
```