# auto increment id based off another field in the database

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table:

[image]

I'd like the version number to auto increment when a record is added but I want it unique to the SoftwareId. I have Version number set to 'Is identity'.

For instance:

```
---
1|1
2|1
2|2
3|1
3|2
3|3
4|1
5|1
5|2
```

So, for each softwareid, there are a set of numbers that increment automatically when a new record is added.

Is this something I can do through Sql Server or will I need to do this through Entity/Linq?

I will be using Entity and Linq to access the data. Will I need to increment the number at the time of the add myself?

Comment: Take a look at this [How to implement auto-incrementing version number column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24788148/how-to-implement-auto-incrementing-version-number-column?noredirect=1#comment38471859_24788148)

Answer (score 0):

If you connect to your database and you have all data in a collection, for example:

```
class Dog
{
     int ID {get; }
     string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Now you have this data in a collection - names `myDogs`(of type: `List<Dog>`)
now you want last ID from this collection, then you can use:

```
var lastID = myDogs.Last().Select(p=>p.ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a table like this:

```
create table dbo.foo
(
  SoftwareID int not null ,
  ID         int not null identity(1,1) ,

  primary key clustered    ( SoftwareID , ID ) ,
  unique      nonclustered (              ID ) ,

)
```

Then we wrap it in a view (and access it via the view), like this:

```
create view dbo.foo_view
as select * ,
          VersionID  = row_number() over (
                         partition by t.SoftwareID
                         order by t.ID
                         )
   from dbo.foo t
```

IF we then seed the table with some sample data:

```
insert dbo.foo ( SoftwareID  ) values ( 1 )
insert dbo.foo ( SoftwareID  ) values ( 2 )
insert dbo.foo ( SoftwareID  ) values ( 3 )
insert dbo.foo ( SoftwareID  ) values ( 1 )
insert dbo.foo ( SoftwareID  ) values ( 2 )
insert dbo.foo ( SoftwareID  ) values ( 3 )
insert dbo.foo ( SoftwareID  ) values ( 1 )
insert dbo.foo ( SoftwareID  ) values ( 2 )
insert dbo.foo ( SoftwareID  ) values ( 3 )
insert dbo.foo ( SoftwareID  ) values ( 2 )
insert dbo.foo ( SoftwareID  ) values ( 2 )
insert dbo.foo ( SoftwareID  ) values ( 1 )
```

we can query the view

```
select *
from dbo.foo_view
```

and get these results

```
SoftwareID ID VersionID
---------- -- ---------
     1      1     1
     1      4     2
     1      7     3
     1     12     4
     2      2     1
     2      5     2
     2      8     3
     2     10     4
     2     11     5
     3      3     1
     3      6     2
     3      9     3
```